# Sum every 9th row starting from the 4th row in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column where there is a number every 9th row. The problem is that my first value starts on 4th row then all the next ones every 9th row. So far I tried this:

`=ArrayFormula(sum(if(mod(row(J:J),9)=0,J:J)))` => sum on J column every 9th row

and this:

`=ArrayFormula(sum(if(mod(row(J4:J),9)=0,J4:J)))` => I thought it would work but gives me the same result as the first one.

Is there a way to start from a row then sum every a number of row in Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glad it worked! Copying over the answer:

You can try something like this: `=J4 + ArrayFormula(sum(if(mod(row(J5:J)-4,9)=0,J5:J)))`

Comment: Note you need to use ; instead of , as a separator

Comment: That depends on your locale setting.